# XSLT 2.0 matching element's content against a list of keywords

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A>
    <B>Dvortsovaya pl 2</B>
    <B>Inzhenernaya ul 4</B>
    <B>xyzul</B>
</A>
```

I'd like to test the content of `<B>` against a list of keywords (in this case: 'ul', 'pl', 'nab') and add an attribute `type='adress'` if one of the keywords is present. 
So expected XML output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <A>
        <B type='adress'>Dvortsovaya pl 2</B>
        <B  type='adress'>Inzhenernaya ul 4</B>
        <B>xyzul</B>
    </A>
```

Since the list of keywords may vary, I'm trying to write a general templete which gets the keywords from a list whithin a variable. I tried to achieve this with a 'loop' template, which obviously does not work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="-1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:variable name="adressKeywords">
        <item n="1">ul</item>
        <item n="2">pl</item>
        <item n="3">nab</item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="B">
        <xsl:call-template name="addAttribute">
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end" select="count($adressKeywords/item)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="addAttribute">
        <xsl:param name="start"/>
        <xsl:param name="end"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$start &lt;= $end">
            <xsl:variable name="reg">(^|\W)<xsl:value-of select="$adressKeywords/item[@n=$start]"
                />($|\W)</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=" matches($text, $reg)">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:attribute name="value">adress</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$start &lt;= $end">
                <xsl:call-template name="addAttribute">
                    <xsl:with-param name="start">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$start+1"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                    <xsl:with-param name="end">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$end"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any idea of how can I get the result (if it's possible at all...)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply write a template for those `B` elements that match an alternative of the keywords:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:param name="adressKeywords">
        <item n="1">ul</item>
        <item n="2">pl</item>
        <item n="3">nab</item>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="regex" select="concat('(^|\W)(', string-join($adressKeywords/item, '|'), ')($|\W)')"/>

    <xsl:template match="B[matches(., $regex)]">
        <B type="address">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </B>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So simple it was! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Making it simpler, add a template for A/* which checks for the presence of the keywords and adds @type:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:variable name="adressKeywords">
    <item>ul</item>
    <item>pl</item>
    <item>nab</item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/A">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="A/*[true() = (for $var in $adressKeywords/* return if(contains(., $var)) then true() else false())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">adress</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: By the way, there is no need of reducing the priority of the default template for "node() | @*"

Comment: You can simplify the predicate in that match to `A/*[some $var in $addressKeywords/* satisfies contains(., $var)]`

Comment: Thank, Ian! That's a nice way. I've got to explore it :)

Comment: The XPath spec calls it a [quantified expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions).  An `=` test is implicitly quantified in XPath, `x = y` means exactly the same as `some $a in x, $b in y satisfies $a eq $b`

Comment: @ Lingamurthy CS: Hi, thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately there was an error in my input XML example: the third <B> element should look like this: `<B>xyzul</B>` (I edited my question). So, in this case your XSLT doesn’t work, because it matches the ‘ul’ string whether it functions as a keyword or not. Sorry for the oversight! I think Martin’s solution is the right one.